# How to run custom python code when server starts with django framework?

Tags: python, django

I have a python file in my app folder in my django project, I want it to run when the server starts, How do I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put your code in `__init__.py` file of your app folder.

Comment: Take care that this code will be run any time you import that package.